# Convert this 5 line JavaScript code to cURL?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

```
$.post("http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",{
                subject : "UMAD!",
                body : "UMAD!",
                recipientid : 2342342
})
```

I'm questioning how I would convert this to cURL.

I need to send the POST request.

I don't know where to start though.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Convert to CURL command line or PHP curl functions?

Answer (score 4):

```
$c = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",
CURLOPT_POST           => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
    'subject' => 'UMAD!',
    'body' => 'UMAD!',
    'recipientid' => '2342342',
)
);
curl_setopt_array($c, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks right. I can't rep you up because I need 15 reputation myself, thank you though.

Comment: It's okay. No need of that.

Comment: Don't forget to specify the **Content-Type**

Comment: Wait, I just ran it on my webserver and it didn't work. Is there a way I could output it to console or something so I can see whats wrong?

Comment: I have a feeling it might be because of the 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

Answer (score 1):

That would be (excluding some headers):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://www.roblox.com/messages/send' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d 'subject=UMAD!&body=UMAD!&recipientid=2342342'
```

Comment: I'm talking about PHP cURL.

Not just the command line, like on your domain too.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, because you technically did what he asked.  The question was just not very well described.